# IntelliJ only compiles files once

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ (Ultimate 2018.1) is not building my project properly. The project is using Maven which doesn't seem to have any problems (all libs are there). The problem is as follows:

Everytime I start up IntelliJ, I am able to build all changes exactly one time. I can change contents of my files and those changes will be contained in the build. But every change I do after that first build is ignored by the build tool. So, every time I build the project (ctrl+f9) after that, I get "All files are up-to-date" and nothing is compiled. (If I am running the app on the application server and try a hot swap, the build says "loaded classes are up to date ...")

Only a restart of the IDE lets me rebuild the project.

**Edit:** As I just found out, a restart of the IDE is not the only possibility to make a build possible again. In the state of not being able to compile, I changed a setting in the compiler settings. After that, I was able to build again. But only once. I then changed the setting back and well, I could build again. Looks like something odd in the IDE. **/Edit**

**Edit2:** Oddly enough, the explicit compiling of the class (ctrl+shift+f9) is working. So the problem circles around the compiling of the whole project. While this is making IntelliJ usable again, it's error prone regarding multiple changed files... **/Edit2**

A few notes and configurations of the project:

- The build produces a .war
- It is deployed on a wildfly (which is not started once in this cycle, so this shouldn't be the root of the problem)
- The exact same project was formerly developed in Eclipse where building and Hot-Swap worked flawlessly (and still do when I try Eclipse again)
- Maven Config:
  [image: Maven configuration]
- Compiler config:
  [image: Compiler configuration]

Comment: Hit CTRL + SHIFT + A  and search "Clear output directory on rebuild". Is it checked?

Comment: @Michael It was checked initially. Please have a look on my edit in the question. It was exactly this option that I toggled on and off.

Comment: Can you try: Project settings > Artifacts > tick 'Include in project build'

Comment: @Michael that option is already ticked on (it wasn't initially, but I tried that one, too). Unfortunately this changes nothing

Comment: I have edited the post again, more odd behaviour from the IDE...

Comment: In what directory is the class that you change is located? Do you use custom plugins? Do you have any specific configuration in Maven for the build? Any errors in [idea.log or build.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) files? Also, do you build only by IDE or you also use Maven build?

Comment: @Andrey The project is inside a git repository and was cloned into a folder named ".git" which was the problem ... IntelliJ couldn't discover the sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the "Build Project" command is the source discovery of IntelliJ. A long time ago, we made the choice to place our sources inside a folder named ".git" (not the folder in the repository), so IntelliJ had problems to discover the code inside that directory. The reason for that was an old approach of Eclipse to clone repositories into a .git folder. The directory looked like this:
C:\dev\.git\workspace and inside that folder was another .git folder (from the repository).
 So, the answer is:

Don't put your git repository in a folder named ".git" or IntelliJ will not compile it (unless you only compile class wise).

Comment: I've tried it with 2018.1.5 and a Maven project inside dev.git folder - did not face such problems. What do you mean by problem with "discover source code"?

Comment: the folder was just named ".git" (like the hidden one in the git repository). So I guess IntelliJ was assuming all files inside that folder could be ignored. I edited my answer as it was misformatted (wrong directory)

Answer (score 0):

Check with Intellij version. As I am using 1.4 community edition and for me its running proper.

Even I have updated few dependencies after building First Time and it get's rebuild automatically. 
So for my understanding what you can do it just check with the Intellij update or change the default directory and rebuild it.

Comment: I am using the latest IntelliJ version from thursday last week